# A Query to return Alphanumeric

Tags: t-sql

Does any have any query that returns apha numerice values only

Sample

Select FirstName,Surname,NationalID From Contacts

Results

FirstName|Surname|NationalID
Tony     |Smith  |934&#fdsaf$34£51
Mary     |Jones  |655^!ffdat@389£2

Expected results

FirstName|Surname|NationalID
Tony     |Smith  |934fdsaf34£51
Mary     |Jones  |655ffdat389£2

In other words i want the query to return numbers and text only :. A-Z and 0-9 only remving '$%^&*(~>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the [patindex function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx).  For example with just selecting the FirstName this will remove the first occurrence of non alphanumeric:

```
SELECT replace(FirstName, substring(FirstName, patindex('%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%', FirstName), 1), '') FROM CONTACTS
```

To expand this to removing all occurrences, move the patindex call into a function [as mentioned here](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-extracting-data-again):

```
CREATE FUNCTION CleanVarchar(@Temp VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN

    WHILE PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%', @Temp) > 0
        SET @Temp = STUFF(@Temp, PATINDEX('%[^a-z^0-9]%', @Temp), 1, '')

    RETURN @TEmp
END
```

Finally call the function

```
Select CleanVarchar(FirstName),CleanVarchar(Surname),CleanVarchar(NationalID) From Contacts
```

Answer (score 1):

use [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) function of sql server

[Sql Server Tips – Removing or Replacing non-alphanumeric characters in strings](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/13/10126948/remove-alpha-char.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with T-SQL only in a neat way.
But you could easily expose such a functionality through a .NET Assembly to the SQL-Server.
There several examples on this topic over the net.